# Error status 404: origin server did not find a current representation

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a netbeans Project with the structure below. When i access localhost:8080/Project/Song it appears the error:

HTTP status 404

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource.

Do you know how where is the issue and how to correct it?

**Project structure:**

```
 Project
        Web Pages
            META-INF
            WEB-INF
               web.xml
               lib
                  jstl-1.2.jar 
           songs.jsp

        Source Packages
            data
                Song.java
```

**Song.java:**

```
package data;    
import org.apache.jena.base.Sys;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


@WebServlet(name = "/Song")
public class Song extends HttpServlet {
    /*protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }*/

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        QueryManager qm = new QueryManager();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = qm.getSongs();
        qm.closeConnections();

        request.setAttribute("result", result.get(0));
        request.setAttribute("id", result.get(1));
        RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher("songs.jsp");
        view.forward(request,response);
    }

    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Songs page");
    }
}
```

**songs.jsp:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Songs List</title>
      </head>
      <body>

        <div id="songs">

          <c:forEach items="${result}" var="item" varStatus="status">
            <a href="/SongPage?name=${result[status.index].replace(" ","+")}&id=${id[status.index]}"> ${result[status.index]} </a> <br />
          </c:forEach>
        </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

**web  xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Song</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Song</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Song</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Song</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: try changing request.getRequestDispatcher("songs.jsp"); to request.getRequestDispatcher("/songs.jsp");

Comment: Thanks, but also dont works!

Comment: Do you need both mapping WebServlet and xml? try removing WebServlet.. Which version ot tomcat?

Comment: <servlet-class>Song</servlet-class>  class name should be packagename.classname

Comment: The version is 8.5. projectdata/Song in the servlet name shows a error "application contexto path could not be started.

Comment: Removing the webservlet it appears the same 404 error.

Comment: I think this is not valid <servlet-class>Song</servlet-class>. you need to give the fully qualified name

Comment: But like that appears the "application path could not be started". Also sometimes it appears this error "http status 500", error instantiating servlet class [Song]. java.lang.ClassNotFoundExpcetion. But with refresh it appears the page with the 404 error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160959/discussion-between-vts-and-ozzyw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both servlet mapping methods. Use one of them. **Annotation method or web.xml** Remove servlet mapping from web.xml file. Means remove below portion

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Song</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Song</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Song</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Song</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The below line is not valid. You need to give the fully qualified name of your class. anyway you dont need this if you have `annotation`

```
<servlet-class>Song</servlet-class>
```

use this.

```
  @WebServlet(name = "Song", urlPatterns = {"/Song"})
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue continues. It appears the 404 error.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with   @WebServlet(name = "Song", urlPatterns = {"/Song"}).